# Segue error objc

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, segue, ios10

HI I keep getting the error reason: 'Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Receiver () has no segue with identifier 'MainToEndUserAgreement''
'

I know for a fact that the controllers are connected and the name is correct for the segue.

[Here is the Story board](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ESpkL.png)

First I tried `[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"MainToEndUserAgreement" sender:self];`

Then after research I tried:
`[instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MainToEndUserAgreement"];`

and

```
`self.storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];`
```

`EndUserAgreementViewController *willthiswork = [[EndUserAgreementViewController alloc] init];`

Neither worked.

Every change I wiped the data from the device and cleaned the project.

What else can I try?

Comment: There are two possible causes; 1. The segue identifier is incorrect; you screen shot seems to indicate that this isn't the case, so 2. The view controller you are performing the segue *from* isn't the one you think it is/have configured in the storyboard.

Comment: The second cause was pretty close to the issue but it made me think. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The error is about a segue called "LoginToMap". But you're focusing on a different segue, "MainToEndUserAgreement". Where are you trying to perform the LoginToMap segue? It seems either that one doesn't exist, or you're sending performSegue to the wrong VC.

edit: Then what is 'self' when you're performing the segue? It is presumably a different VC than the storyboard's segue's source VC.

Whatever 'self' is, it doesn't have a segue of that name.

Comment: My bad I was messing with the name to test with will edit it now.

Comment: If you're not going to upvote you might not get many more answers :)

Comment: It was close much deeper in the code the storyboard was lost and it couldn't find the segue I just created this account so I can't publicly upvote it. But thank you!